# Android: Multiple video error

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have four videos that are loading on one activity from a url. Now the problem is that when i start the activity all videos plays at the same time. What actually i want is to stop all videos at start and when user clicks on the play button the selected video should be played. If someone has any tutorial or any help with code regarding this problem please help me.

**Edit:**

Here is my Activity code.

```
MediaController mediaController; 
    private static String Video_url="http://mywebsite.com/files/video1.mp4";
    private static String Video_url2="http://mywebsite.com/files/video2.mp4";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.url_activity_video);

         VideoView video = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        VideoView video2 = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView2);

        mediaController = new MediaController(this);


        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);



        mediaController.setAnchorView(video);
        String Video=Video_url;
        video.setMediaController(mediaController);
        video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(Video));
        video.start();


        ///////////// Video 2 /////////
        mediaController.setAnchorView(video2);
        String Video2=Video_url2;
        video.setMediaController(mediaController);
        video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(Video2));
        video.start();


    }
```

Comment: Where are you loading these videos? Please post your code.

Comment: Post the code you are tying in . . . .

Comment: @VIGNESH here is the code check

Comment: @SiddharthVyas see my code

Comment: @user3294034 Check my answer.Let me know if you find any problem.

Comment: @SiddharthVyas Then if during play of a video a user clicks on button2 then how can I stop the first one at that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create a buttons and on button click listeners you can add following code :

```
 button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
     playVideo1(your video url)
 }
 });

  button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
     playVideo2(your video url)
 }
 });

public static void playVideo1(String urlPath) {

 VideoView mVideoview; // Added this line
 mVideoView =(VideoView) findViewByid(R.yourvideoviewid);

try {
// Start the MediaController
MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(mContext);
mediacontroller.setAnchorView(mVideoview);
// Get the URL from String VideoURL
Uri mVideo = Uri.parse(urlPath);
mVideoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
mVideoview.setVideoURI(mVideo);

} catch (Exception e) {
Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
e.printStackTrace();

}

mVideoview.requestFocus();
mVideoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
// Close the progress bar and play the video
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
mVideoview.start();

}
});

mVideoview.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

}
});

}
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: at this line i am getting an error `mVideoview.requestFocus();` mVideoview cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Should i ini this mVideoview once another at this and if i do that it gives me an error at the play method because its a static and java will not alloaw me to make static ref. to non-statics

Comment: Any method for stopping video on selection of second video?

Comment: mVideoview is an object of VideoView class.

Comment: Any method for stopping video on selection of second video?

Answer (score 0):

You are starting both the videos in `onCreate` Method , So it is starts playing both the video at the same time .

Do as below ,

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
     video1.start();
 }
 });

  button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
     video2.start();
 }
 });
```

And also that in the code you posted the `video` object is initialized 2 times .

It should be `video2` for second video , As per your code