# Can't play this video android from sdcard

Tags: android, mediacontroller, android-videoview

I downloaded the video from server url and store to sdcard, it's stored fine as a .mp4 format. But when i access this video from VideoView for playing video using MediaController, i'm getting can't play this video error. The folder name is Video.

```
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(ImageTargets.this);
                   mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
                   videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

                   String sdpath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                   String video_path=sdpath+"Video" +"focusvideo.mp4";        
                   videoView.setVideoPath(video_path);
videoView.start();
```

Comment: try out if you have to `.prepare()` or `.prepareAsync()` before `.start()`

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/22377177/1785412

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` method return type is `File` instead of sdcard path as String. To get sdcard path call `getAbsolutePath()` of file as:

```
String sdpath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
String video_path=str_path+"/Video/" +"focusvideo.mp4";        
videoView.setVideoPath(video_path);
```

Comment: @user3743552 : what string you are getting in `video_path` variable ?

Comment: I have focusvideo.mp4 video inside Video folder. I need to get this video and play

Answer (score 0):

try this :-

```
   VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
   myVideoView.setVideoPath(SrcPath);
   myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
   myVideoView.requestFocus();
   myVideoView.start();
```